# Is it OK to ask questions that give a shader and ask "How can I optimize this?"

Tags: discussion

Is it OK to ask these kinds of questions or are they not focused enough / too much "do my homework for me"-like?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like it would be too broad. So it's not classified as too broad you should tell us:

- The specific functionality you're interested in optimizing
- What you've tried already
- Exactly what about it isn't working
- Exactly how you want it to work

Further, providing any profiler information or evidence you used to decide that this was the functionality you needed to improve would likely be useful to the person answering you.

Comment: I would like to add that otherwise, it will only be list generator of possible optimization techniques that may or may not work in your case.